# verificar se Radiobutton com RepeatDirection, gerados no DataGrid estão checados

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um RadionButton com RepeatDirection que é gerado no meu DataGrid, botão sim e não.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText ="Reevio" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="9">
                    <ItemTemplate>                         
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLIndicaReenvio" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RBLIndicaReevio_SelectedIndexChanged">     
                            <asp:ListItem Value="S" Text="Sim" ></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="N" Text="Não" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

E aqui, tenho uma um uma txb e um botão também gerados no grid.

```
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText ="Digite Seu E-Mail" Visible ="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="9">
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TXBEmail" Visible ="false" runat="server" Width="200" CssClass="txbEmail" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="BTNEnviar" Visible ="false" runat="server" Text="Enviar" Width="60" OnClick="BTNEnviar_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o code behind

```
protected void RBLIndicaReevio_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList objectClick = (RadioButtonList)sender;
        int columnReenvio = Util.getColIndexByHeader(dgRegistros, "Digite Seu E-Mail");

        foreach (DataGridItem dr in dgRegistros.Items)
        {
            RadioButtonList radio;
            TextBox email;
            Button enviar;

            radio = ((RadioButtonList)dr.Cells[columnReenvio].FindControl("RBLIndicaReenvio"));
            email = ((TextBox)dr.Cells[columnReenvio].FindControl("TXBEmail"));
            enviar = ((Button)dr.Cells[columnReenvio].FindControl("BTNEnviar"));

            if (radio == objectClick)
            {
                if (radio.SelectedValue == "S")
                {
                    dgRegistros.Columns[Util.getColIndexByHeader(dgRegistros, "Digite Seu E-Mail")].Visible = true;
                    dr.Cells[columnReenvio].Visible = true;
                    enviar.Visible = true;
                    email.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //dgRegistros.Columns[Util.getColIndexByHeader(dgRegistros, "Digite Seu E-Mail")].Visible = false;

                    dr.Cells[columnReenvio].Visible = true;
                    enviar.Visible = false;
                    email.Visible = false;

                }
            }

        }
```

como eu poderia validar se todos os os radios estão como Não ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
  bool todosOpcaoSim = true;
  foreach (DataGridItem dtR in dgRegistros.Items)
  {
    RadioButtonList radio = (RadioButtonList)dtR.Cells[columnReenvio].FindControl("RBLIndicaReenvio"));

    if (radio.SelectedValue.Equals("N"))
      todosOpcaoSim = false;
  }
```

Após passar por esse bloco de código a sua variável vai guardar se todos estão marcados ou não como sim.

Comment: show man! valeu pela ajuda. consegui de uma outra forma.

Comment: contei o número de linhas e comparei com o numero de botões selecionados.


int rowCount = dgRegistros.Items.Count;
            int countRadio = 0;

            RadioButtonList radioaux;

            foreach (DataGridItem dr in dgRegistros.Items)
            {
                radioaux = ((RadioButtonList)dr.Cells[columnReenvio].FindControl("RBLIndicaReenvio"));
                if (radioaux.SelectedValue == "N")
                {
                    countRadio = countRadio + 1;
                }

            }

Comment: A lógica é a mesma praticamente, o que muda é que vc usou um contador ao invés de um booleano. Não esqueça de marcar a resposta que resolveu seu problema pra poder fechar o tópico

Comment: sim man, eu fiz ele depois que li sua resposta, valeu :D

Answer (score -1):

consegui resolver contando o números de linhas e de botões selecionados, e comparando os 2 :D

```
        int rowCount = dgRegistros.Items.Count;

        int countRadio = 0;

        RadioButtonList radioaux;

        foreach (DataGridItem dr in dgRegistros.Items)
        {
            radioaux = ((RadioButtonList)dr.Cells[columnReenvio].FindControl("RBLIndicaReenvio"));
            if (radioaux.SelectedValue == "N")
            {
                countRadio = countRadio + 1;
            }

        }

        if (countRadio == rowCount)
        {
            dgRegistros.Columns[Util.getColIndexByHeader(dgRegistros, "Digite Seu E-Mail")].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dgRegistros.Columns[Util.getColIndexByHeader(dgRegistros, "Digite Seu E-Mail")].Visible = true;
        }
```